# WordPress Plugin ajax doesn't work because of admin_init hook

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I make an ajax request on site front-end in js:

```
jQuery.post( ajaxurl, {
                 action: 'test',
                 method: 'magic'
             },
             function(response){});
```

Request is sent. In its response I see the whole content of a current page (html), but it should be just `ok` or `error`.

After some tests I understood, that registered ajax action just never fired:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'test_ajax');
function test_ajax(){
    // during ajax I'm not here
    die('test');
}
```

The request is done by logged in user, so no wp_ajax_nopriv required.

I have opened the admin-ajax.php file and tried to debug it. Everything is fine (I see the post request I'm sending) until I reach line 41 (as for WP 3.5.1):

```
do_action( 'admin_init' );
```

Right after this line the code is not executed.

In WordPress admin area the same plugin does send some ajax requests as well - and they work. Those ajax handlers are in the same file, as written above.

I have no idea why this happened. Any help?

Comment: Found the issue - in difficulties of understanding of init and bp_init actions. 
Did some code refactoring - now it works as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms and you might have the same problem. In my case, the problem arise from  the fact that I have created special roles. When a user with that a role tried to enter WP-Admin, I have added a script that prevents the user from access.

This is the script that results in faulty ajax-calls and responses. The correct way to prevent the user is this;

```
function redirect_non_admin_user() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_admin_user' );
```

This has solved my problem and might solve yours as well...hope it helps

Comment: As I wrote in a comment under my question - I found where was the problem - hooks firing order.